# Error on see nestjs version and start new pro ject

Tags: nestjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjauh.png)

Error on see NestJS Version

if (er?.code !== 'ENOENT') {
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

Comment: which node version you are using ?

Comment: The problem is the node version, change for a recent node version and work, thank you